# What is the solution of the matrix equation $A X + X A' + B X B' + C = 0$ for $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I know that the matrix equation $A X + X A' + C = 0$ is in the form of the time-continuous Lyapunov equation, so solving for $X$ is pretty trivial since the solution already and numeric solvers already exists. However, I don't know how to solve for $X$ when $B X B'$ is added to the equation so that the equation reads:

$$A X + X A' + B X B' + C = 0$$

This is no longer in a form I am familiar with and I was wondering if there is any known solution out there. It should be noted that both $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian ($A= A'$ and $B= B'$) for my purposes. If it helps, $C$ is an identity matrix for my purposes as well.

Comment: There are various norms about whether or not to use TeX when plain text can do, but, if you *do* use plain text, then please be careful about tripping the Markdown parser:  A*X + X*A' `A*X + X*A'` is parsed with "X + X" in italics, which is not what you want.  $A X + X A'$ `A X + X A'` is almost certainly preferable.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Although similar to the continuous Linear Quadratic Ricatti Equation, to consult here, it is not. May I ask where does this equation comes from?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto yeah, so I do a lot of research into open quantum system using density matrix formalism and the differential equation describing the system of spins at steady state basically boils down to this equation. I can solve this as a function of time easily, but computationally it’s very slow and I need something much faster for my purposes.

Comment: Are you sure the statement leads to it? Take a look on the Ricatti equation formalism as I mentioned. What is the mathematical statement?

Comment: I recommend to: guess an initial solution for X e.g. the identity matrix, set the RHS as the equation error, calculate its norm and iterate the norm with the algorithm https://github.com/brunolnetto/baryopt for some high iterations number.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto The full mathematical statement is $\frac{dp}{dt} = [H,p] - c_1 \{P_s,p\} - c_2 \{P_t,p\} + G + L$. Here H is the Hamiltonian of my spin system, Ps and Pt are spin projection operators G is proportional to an identity matrix and L is the Linblad operator. Here brackets $[]$ are the commutator and $\{\}$ is the anti commutator. The Linblad operator, $L = sum_{i=0}^{n=9} (LpL' - 1/2 \{L'L,p\})$

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto how fast is that process? I need steady state solutions iterated 4000 data points per trace. Then then repeat that over a few hundred to a 10 of thousands of traces. So time to solve is critical

Comment: Try it once and see. It requires an objective function and 1+m^2 hyperparameters. The variable m corresponds to the unknown variable dimension.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto what is the exact function within the GitHub repo?

Comment: Function: https://github.com/brunolnetto/baryopt/blob/master/versions/python/drecexpbary.py
Examples: https://github.com/brunolnetto/baryopt/tree/master/versions/python/examples